# Sending file to API from form without uploading?

Tags: php

I have a form that sends a file to an external API, but I don't want it to make a copy on my server, how can I upload the file directly to the API and not save it on my server, or at least keep it in the temp directory? Here is my code:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir.$_FILES['file']['name'])) {
   $status = 1;

    //validate
    $url = 'https://api.dostuff.com';
    $apikey = 'xxx';
     
    $header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');
    $path_to_document = realpath($target_dir.$_FILES['file']['name']);
     
    if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
        
        $image1 = curl_file_create($path_to_document);
    } else {

        $image1 = '@' . $path_to_document;
    }
     
    $fields = array('file' => $image1, 'apikey' => $apikey);
    $resource = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($resource),true);
    curl_close($resource);
     
}
```

Edit: The API needs the file to be an image and the `tmp_name` is stored as like `tmp/php/phpXpMgYo` with no extension. Is there any work around?

Comment: _"or at least keep it in the temp directory"_ - Remove the `move_uploaded_file()` (since that function is for moving the file from the temp directory) and use `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` instead of `$path_to_document`.

Comment: I just figured that out, but here's the issue - the API needs it to be a certain file type, and the tmp_name has no file extension. Any work around for this?

Comment: If you check [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php) about `curl_file_create()`, you can see that you can pass the mime and the name of the file as the second and third argument. Something like: `curl_file_create($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["file"]["type"], $_FILES["file"]["name"])`